# Freebase MQL filter where value != null?

Tags: freebase, mql

I'm trying to write an MQL query that filters out null values.

The query I have now (can be executed using the [MQL Query Editor](http://www.freebase.com/tools/queryeditor)):

```
[
  {
    "/common/topic/image" : [
      {
        "id" : null
      }
    ],
    "article" : [
      {
        "content" : null
      }
    ],
    "name" : "bill gates",
    "type" : "/common/topic"
  }
]
```

The results I am getting:

```
[
  {
    "/common/topic/image" : [
      {
        "id" : "/guid/9202a8c04000641f8000000004fb4c01"
      },
      {
        "id" : "/wikipedia/images/commons_id/4486276"
      }
    ],
    "article" : [
      {
        "content" : null
      },
      {
        "content" : "/guid/9202a8c04000641f800000000903535d"
      }
    ],
    "name" : "Bill Gates",
    "type" : "/common/topic"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can filter out the "content" : null match in the "article" array at query time.  I looked through the MQL documentation but I didn't see a clear way to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To filter out articles that don't have any content assigned to them you'll have to expand the content id attribute and set the optional directive to false.

```
[
  {
    "/common/topic/image" : [
      {
        "id" : null
      }
    ],
    "article" : [
      {
        "content" : {
          "id" : null,
          "optional" : false
        }
      }
    ],
    "name" : "bill gates",
    "type" : "/common/topic"
  }
]
```

This will give you the following result:

```
[
  {
    "/common/topic/image" : [
      {
        "id" : "/guid/9202a8c04000641f8000000004fb4c01"
      },
      {
        "id" : "/wikipedia/images/commons_id/4486276"
      }
    ],
    "article" : [
      {
        "content" : {
          "id" : "/guid/9202a8c04000641f800000000903535d"
        }
      }
    ],
    "name" : "Bill Gates",
    "type" : "/common/topic"
  }
]
```

For more information about using the optional directive see the documentation [here](http://mql.freebaseapps.com/ch03.html#optionaldirective).

Comment: Who are you and how to you know so much about MQL? ;)

Comment: Haha, I'm just a member of the Freebase community who has been hacking around in MQL for a year or so. I'm happy to be able to help people learn the ropes and hopefully get more developers building applications using the Freebase data.

Comment: when I switch the optional flag to false, it tells me: "Query too difficult."